# CruiseControl.Net "header.xsl" changes not showing in the dashboard

Tags: iis, cruisecontrol.net

I've added a handful of new builds to a long standing CruiseControl.Net setup. Everything has been smooth up until this point. Now, any changes I make to the **header.xsl** file do not display on the build results dashboard page. This behavior only appeared after the weekend, and I'm not seeing any errors from CC.Net. Any clue as to what might be causing this? I've already attempted restarting both CC.Net and IIS.

Current CC.Net version info: 1.5.7256.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing something related to dashboard configuration (or XSL files) you should

1. restart web server
2. restart ccnet

From my experience

- using ccnet as service + apache + mod_asp, I need to restart only ccnet service.
- using ccnet as service + IIS, I need to restart IIS and sometimes to restart the PC !

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the correct header.xsl?

For the web dashboard you want to change webdashboard\xsl\header.xsl, and may need to reload the dashboard config before you see the change.

The server\xsl\header.xsl file is used when using the EmailPublisher.