# Changes in .xsl file not reflecting on ccnet dashboard

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, dashboard

I am trying to make some changes in my cruise control the web dashboard.

I modified the corresponding .xsl file, but the changes does not seem to reflect back on the dahsboard.

I have tried the following:

```
        - Restart ccnet service.
        - Restart IIS.
```

I am using ccnet version 1.6.7

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please tell us the path where do you changed the files

Comment: I am encountering the same phenomenon, and it is indeed very weird: I did numerous successful changes to the XSL file, so I know for a fact which one is the right one. Until, all of a sudden, those changes stopped being reflected in the CC.NET output. The output is still generated based on my last successfully changed XSL version, but nothing I do to the XSL file now - not even deliberately inserting a syntax error, or deleting the changed file - is picked up by CC.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this tool

http://www.voidtools.com/download.php

Find all copies of your .xsl file.

Make a small (text only) change in the xsl file.......and find the one it is actually using.

My guess is that you have 2 of the same xsl, and you're updating the wrong one.

Comment: That's not a "dumb guess" on my part.  That's using CruiseControl.NET myself and having a "D'oh" moment..............

Comment: Like I said ...... "been there"..........my other hint.  When "developing" for CC.NET (like your xsl changes for example)......run the command line version (instead of starting the cc.net service through Control-Panel/Services).  This way..you can see "hints" in the console application.   After you get everything worked out.....then re-engage the CC.NET service.

Comment: I can now confirm that having the right file may not be enough. I was repeatedly editing a single XSL file and checking the changes in the CC.NET Dashboard. At one point, the changes stopped being reflected. I tried multiple times, but nothing I did to the XSL file - the very same I had successfully edited before - was reflected in the Dashboard. Then, I restarted IIS, whereupon changes were suddenly visible again in the Dashboard. Also see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4726533/1430156).

Answer (score 0):

Also clear the cache of the browser, or do a force-refresh.

If that does not help, check that there is nothing wrong with the xsl.
Simple check : alter the xsl so that it adds some text that must always be visible in the output.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache too. But, no changes still.
Also, I made a change in the already-existing text in the xsl. This is also not reflected.